# How to put together a roku toolchain

Tags: c, roku

I am looking to port something in C to the roku platform and I think I need a toolchain to compile these resources. I noticed [this link](http://www.roku.com/opensource) that talked about the tools that were used and [this link](http://www.jpsaman.org/node/3) seems to suggest such a thing is possible. However, when i try to telnet into the default port I don't get a response and I can't find another port that will allow the su command.

Answer (score 0):

The public Roku SDK only supports apps written in BrightScript, so this currently isn't possible.